# Listview Text Font

Tags: android, listview

I can't seem to find what am looking for.

I would like to know how to change all the textview fonts in all my listviews. I have my text font but when i try to apply it to code it only works for one textview1 etc.

I have been reading that i need a custom adapter to change listview styles but i don't know where to start as i am very new to android and coding. I guess am looking for a site that will get me started if anyone can help.

custom style listview for dummies lets say ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is tons of information and tutorials on creating custom `ListViews`. I'll link some tutorials here but you really could have found what you needed by just doing a little bit more searching.

- [Creating Custom Adapter and ListView 1](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429)
- [Creating Custom Adapter and ListView 2](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

If you have any questions or run into trouble with these I am willing to help.